# Create button on div after animation complete

Tags: jquery, html, button, jquery-animate

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href = "login.css" />

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var swidth = $(window).width();
            var sheight = $(window).height();

            $(document).ready(function(){


                $("#box").animate({ 

                    top: (sheight*0.22)+"px",
                    left: (swidth*0.25)+"px",
                    width:(swidth*0.3)-40+"px",
                    height: (sheight*0.35)-40+"px",

                }, 2000, function(){

                    $('<input type="button" value="My button">').appendTo(this)
                    .button().click(function(){ 

                        alert('I was clicked!');

                    });
                });


                });

        </script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <header>    

        </header>

        <section>

            <div id="box"> 
            </div>


        </section>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I was hoping that because I appended the button after the '.animate. it would wait till the animation is finished. But no luck.

The problem is the div is very small at the beginning of the animation so the button barely fits inside the div, which looks bad. So I just want the button to appear after the animation is complete and the div is at it's full size.

Thanks for any answers in advance.

Comment: Read the documentation for the `animate()` function. There is a callback parameter, which is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was no reason for the code to stop while the asynchronous animation started.

You must do the appending in the complete callback, which is executed when the animation is finished :

```
$("#box").animate({ 
        top: sheight*0.22+"px",
        left: swidth*0.25+"px",
        width: swidth*0.3+"px",
        height: sheight*0.35+"px",
}, 2000, function(){
      $('<input type="button" value="My button">').appendTo(this)
      .button().click(function(){ 
           alert('I was clicked!');
      });
});
```

Note that I also changed the appending code. you were applying the `button` and `click` functions to the `#box` element, not to the new input.

EDIT :

Now that you show your code, it's visible you don't import jQuery UI. You must do it. See http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Comment: The alert doesn't seem to come up when the button is clicked on either answers. Does anyone know why?

Comment: still doesn't seem to work. I must have some other error in my code. I'll type it out up top.

Comment: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Is this not it, version 1.10.2 ??

Comment: This is jQuery, not jQuery UI (which is a second lib which uses jQuery). If you don't want to use jQueryUI but just jQuery, remove `.button()`.

Comment: Thanks a million, I didn't realize this and to be honest I can't go on using jQuery without jQueryUI, so I'll look into that. In the meantime I've removed the .button. I really appreciate your fast replies and all the help you've given me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

the use complete callback

```
var swidth = $(window).width();
var sheight = $(window).height();

$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#box").animate({ 

        top: sheight*0.22+"px",
        left: swidth*0.25+"px",
        width: swidth*0.3+"px",
        height: sheight*0.35+"px"
    }, 2000, function(){
        function(){
            $(this).append('<input type="button" value="My button">').button().click(function(){ 
                alert('I was clicked!');
            });
        }
    } )



});
```

Comment: Any idea why the alert button shows but the function doesn't run?